# Confused about the Azure Redis Connection Limit (Up to X Connections)

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-redis-cache

I'm looking into building some signalR applications in .NET hosted in Azure (Self hosting workers).

I want to scaleOut and setup a Backplane using Azure Redis, however when i've gone to setup a new Redis Cache i've got confused to what the 'Up to X connections' actually means.

For example, the 'CO Basic 250MB Cache' has 'Up to 256 connections' and the 'C1 Standard 1GB Cache' has 'Up to 1,000 connections'

To confirm, can i take 'Up to 256 connections' to mean that i could (In theory) have up to 256 worker threads all pushing SignalR messages around at once ... Or does this mean the total amount of connections (users) from my website that are connected to my SignalR and in turn, pushing messages around the Redis Cache?

Obviously, if it means 256 workers thats fine - But if it means the total number of different connections from my website, then that is a deal breaker

Thanks and sorry if this is a silly question!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The connection limit is not about the number of worker threads that are reading from or writing to Redis.  It is about physical TCP connections.  Redis supports [pipelining](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining).  Many of the client libraries are thread safe so that you can use the same physical connection object to write from multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: Just so i know what that translates too ... You're saying that with my SignalR example, if a TCPIP connection was made to one of the worker threads from an instance of my website, that would count as a connection?

Comment: Yes, a "connection" means one TCP/IP socket connection.  I can't comment on how that maps to workers threads in SignalR because I don't use that technology.  In general, connection management is owned by the client app.  The client app can chose to create one connection and share it between worker threads or it can create a new connection for each worker thread.  In general, it is best to create connections and re-use to avoid the overhead associated with creating the connection itself.

Comment: Thank Jon - Looks like i'll be going with a SQL backplane then!

Comment: I would not consider this the correct answer, as @JonCole does not have any experience with SignalR, and there is now even more confusion. The Redis client is SignalR, not the end-user

Answer (score 2):

From a SignalR backplane perspective, the SignalR websocket connections do not correlate with the number of connections to a Redis Cache server.

A user's SignalR connection is with the SignalR Hub server, which in turn acts as a Redis client in case of a scaleout. 
The Redis client in signalr connects using the standard ConnectionMultiplexer which handles the connections to redis internally. And the guidance is to use a single multiplexer for the whole application, or a minimal number.

The Redis client is to send/receive messages and not create/access keys for each operation, so it makes sense to have a single channel open and to have all the messages being exchanged on that single channel.

I am not sure how that connectionmultiplexer manages Redis connections, but we do use Redis backplane for SignalR scaleout on Azure for our application.

We load tested the app and **with around 200 thousand always active Signalr websocket connections scaled out over 10 servers, the Azure Redis cache connections count hovered around 50 on average, almost never going above even 60.**.

I think it is safe to say that the connection limits on Azure Redis cache are not a limiting factor for SignalR, unless you scale out to hundreds of servers.